# Inclusion-Exclusion Non-Complement Way

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I was working on this problem and I can solve it by applying the same technique as suggested in this answer: [Inclusion-Exclusion Problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936525/inclusion-exclusion-problem)

"A widget inspector inspects 12 widgets and finds that exactly 3 are defective. The widgets then get all mixed up and the inspector has to find the 3 defective widgets again by testing one.Find the probability that the inspector will now have to test at least 9 widgets"

However, for my own sake I'm trying to also get the same answer by counting the ways the widget inspector doesn't find the defective widgets amongst the first 8 widgets using inclusion-exlusion, however, my answers don't match up so I was hoping someone could point out what I am doing wrong:

$$
 \frac{\binom{12}{1}11!- \binom{12}{2}10!+\binom{12}{3}9!-\binom{12}{4}8!+\binom{12}{5}7!-\binom{12}{6}6!+\binom{12}{7}5!-\binom{12}{8}4!}{12!}
$$

Edit (Reasoning for the numerator): I wanted to use inclusion-exclusion to count on the numerator the number of ways that the first 8 widgets were non-defective. I can see now that that's not what I have done at all.  My reasoning for the first term in the numerator was that if the first widget was non-defective then the remaining widgets could be chosen in 11! ways and the first widgets could be chosen in 12C1 ways. I feel like this is were I have a gap in my understanding which I am trying to fill and Im struggling to make the proper connections.

Comment: Please explain the reasoning for your numerator.

Comment: Updated the question with my reasoning.

Comment: Don't count ways to arrange the widgets. Count ways to select *positions* for the three defective widgets, in the inspection line up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, for my own sake I'm trying to also get the same answer by counting the ways the widget inspector doesn't find the defective widgets amongst the first 8 widgets using inclusion-exlusion,

No, you want the probability that the inspector does not find the *third* defective widget among the first eight to be inspected.  It is fine to find one or two defective widgets among them, as long as all three are not there.

---

You can count the favoured case as selecting none, one, or two *places for* the three defective widgets among the first eight inspections, and *places for* the remainder among the last four scheduled to be inspected.

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{8}{0}\dbinom{4}{3}+\dbinom{8}{1}\dbinom{4}{2}+\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{12}3}$$

You can count the favoured case by ways to select *places for* the first two defective widgets when the third defective widget is the ninth, tenth, eleventh, or twelfth inspected.

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{8}{2}+\dbinom{9}{2}+\dbinom{10}{2}+\dbinom{11}{2}}{\dbinom{12}{3}}$$

Or you may use the suggestion of excluding the unfavoured case.

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{12}{3}-\dbinom{8}{3}}{\dbinom{12}{3}}$$